# turn off confimation of mailchimp

Tags: mailchimp

i want to turn off confirmation mail of mail-chimp. I have wondered every where but not getting any response from any site. How i disable . Not any mail just user click subscribe the newsletter and redirect to current site. No need to any confirmation mail from mail chimp. Is this possible.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You cannot disable MailChimp's "double opt-in" feature if you are serving one of their proprietary subscription forms.  The only way to disable the confirmation email is to create a custom subscription form that invokes the MailChimp API using the `'double_optin'      => false` parameter.

See [MailChimp API v2.0 documentation](http://apidocs.mailchimp.com/api/2.0/lists/subscribe.php) for more info.

Comment: I think this option is now removed. cant find it in the docs.

Answer (score 0):

I see you added a tag "wordPress" to the question. If this is really WordPress-related question, then simply use WordPress MailChimp plugin that allows you to control this from the settings page, like [Chimpy Lite](http://wordpress.org/plugins/chimpy-lite/) or any other alternative.

No need to dig into API specs if you are using WordPress and are happy with using third party plugins.

Comment: Is this an answer?

Answer (score -1):

To enable or disable the final welcome email from your audience settings, follow these steps.

Login to your Mailchimp dashboard

Click on Audience

Then click on "Signup forms"

Then click / Select "Form builder" option.

You will find Drop down "Forms and Response Emails"

Select "Final welcome email"

You will find a checkbox "Send a final welcome Email". If you want that email to be sent, then keep it checked. Other wise uncheck it to not send final email.

For more details refer - https://mailchimp.com/help/enable-or-disable-final-welcome-email/